# React - Loop for render

Tags: reactjs

I'm starting to learn React. I retrieve my data from an API and I would like to create x components as long as there are objects in my object array retrieving from the API.

```js
import React, {Component} from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import Member from "./Member";

class Members extends Component {

    state = {
        members : {},
        text: ''
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('http://localhost:8080/api/v1/members')
            .then(res => {
                const members = res.data.result;
                this.setState({members});
                console.log(res.data)
            })
            .catch(err => console.log("toto:"+err))
    }

    render() {
        for (const member in this.state.members) {
            return (
                <Member name='toto'/>
            );
        }
    }
    
}

export default Members
```

**Error: Members(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.**

---

I block on this type of operation..

Comment: are you sure there are objects in your `state.members`?

Comment: You can render a list of elements, you can not return multiple times inside a function. What is your `members` object? I think it should be an array, not an Object, then you can easily `map()` it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Make members an array

To make members an array you can use entries.

```
return (
  this.state.members && Object.entries(this.state.members)
    .map(([memberKey, memberData]) => <MemberComonent key={memberKey} {...memberData} />)
)
```